# Symfony2 : Override Validator of a Bundle

Tags: symfony, inheritance, overriding, bundle, validation

I'm using [OhDateExtraValidatorBundle](https://github.com/ollieLtd/OhDateExtraValidatorBundle), and because my [Pull Request](https://github.com/ollieLtd/OhDateExtraValidatorBundle/pull/1) hasn't been accepted yet I'll need to override it locally.

I read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) but couldn't make it work for a validator constraint.

Here is what I did :

- Created a new Bundle (so I can override more than one extern bundle), called *MyDateExtraValidatorBundle*
- Added the `getParent()` method :

  `public function getParent()
  {
      return 'OhDateExtraValidatorBundle';
  }`
- Wrote my modification in the same path than the original bundle :

  ```
  namespace MYVENDOR\MyDateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints;

  use Oh\DateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\DateExtraValidator as ConstraintValidator;

  class DateExtraValidator extends ConstraintValidator
  {
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
      parent::validate($value, Constraint $constraint);

      if (null === $value || '' === $value){
          return;
      }


      if(is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString')) {
          $value = (string) $value;
      }
      if (!$dateTime->getTimestamp())
      {
         $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidMessage);
         return;
      } 
    }
  }
  ```

But it's never loaded.

I also tried using directly the name of my bundle in the entity (with the custom validator) class, but doesn't work either.

```
use MYVENDOR\MyDateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints as OhAssert;
```

=>

```
The annotation "@MYVENDOR\MyDateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\DateExtra" [...]  does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

**What's the right way to do ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) does not currently allow overriding [validation metadata](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#validation-metadata).
There is also a [pending issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2841) on this subject.

As a workaround, I would create my own validator.

<kbd>**Acme/FooBundle/Validator/Constraints/MyDateExtra.php**</kbd>

Here, you just extend the base metadata, to keep the messages and configuration.
*`@Annotation` allows your class to be called via [annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#creating-constraint-class)*.

```
use Oh\DateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\DateExtra;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class MyDateExtra extends DateExtra
{
}
```

<kbd>**Acme/FooBundle/Validator/Constraints/MyDateExtraValidator.php**</kbd>

Here, you extend the behaviour of the base validator with your own logic.

```
use Oh\DateExtraValidatorBundle\Validator\Constraints\DateExtraValidator;

class MyDateExtraValidator extends DateExtraValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        parent::validate($value, Constraint $constraint);

        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if(is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString')) {
            $value = (string) $value;
        }

        if (!$dateTime->getTimestamp()) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidMessage);
        } 
    }
}
```

You should now be able to use it into your model.

```
use Acme\FooBundle\Validator\Constraints as Extra;

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @Extra\MyDateExtra
     */
    protected $time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed, works perfectly after adding the namespaces !
Thought, why can't it be the "normal" way to override bundle Validators ? It's prettty clean and doesn't need lots of lines of code..!

Comment: @Bonswouar It should be the *"normal way"*, this functionality just have not been implemented yet, as given in the documentation links: *"In progress"*.

Comment: What do you mean by implemented, like documented ?
Btw I've got [another issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403366/symfony2-recursive-validation) if you want to take a look! ;)

Comment: @Bonswouar It means that they are supposed to develop (and document) this functionnality (override validations metadata) in the future.