# Symfony2 : Recursive Validation

Tags: symfony, recursion, validation

I've got an entity with some validators (**not a form**).

So I use `$validator->validate($entity)`, but it doesn't validate my sub-ojects (the entity class has some others entity classes with some validators).

Is there an "automatic" way to do this, or I have to do `$errorList->addAll($validator->validate($entity));` for each of them ?

Comment: You can use the annotation [`@Assert\Valid`](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) on the property

Comment: That's it, thanks !!
I thought `@Assert\Type(...)` would be enough..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow recursive validation over objects you can simply use the Constraint [`@Assert\Valid`](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

Example
Say a person has a mandatory last name

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @var string
     */
    protected $lastName;
}
```

And you have a product, which have a buyer (`Person`)

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @var Person
     */
    protected $buyer;
}
```

By having `NotNull` and `Valid`, each time you validate the `Product` model it will check that:

- It has a buyer
- The buyer has a `lastName`

Comment: I would add the `@Assert\Type(...\Person)` to be sure it's a Person object. :)

Comment: @Bonswouar Actually, you don't have to. Since property is locked, you should have a `setBuyer(Person $person)` method. PHP will trigger an error if the given type is wrong